# Powershell: Dynamic email based on query results

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell I have a sql query results that I want to break apart and email to each user base on the users name and or email in the query.  So I would like to email Maria only her line and email Jose only his line (base on example below). Also the same user might show up multiple times in the query so I want to just send them one email with all of their results. I called this dynamic emailing but not sure what other users called it. Again thanks for any pointers.  I have the query and

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     email         Name

---

```
151      11     1588        900       0.06   Jose@gmail.com       jose                                                                                                                                                    
235      14     4024       2408              Frank@gmail.com     Frank                                                                                                                                                  
328      17     4936       3728              Frank@gmail.com     Frank                                                                                                                                                  
169      10     1744       3064       0.05   Maria@gmail.com      Maria
```

powershell code i have some far... just gives me the query results for everyone, I am not sure how to breakup the results and email to each user their own results from the query.

```
$query = [system.io.file]::ReadAllText('C:\temp\QUERY.sql')
$Header = [system.io.file]::ReadAllText('C:\temp\header.txt')
$mycss = [system.io.file]::ReadAllText('C:\temp\my.css')


$queryreults = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $query -ServerInstance "SQLserver" -Username $username - 
Password $pw  | Select * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray, HasErrors 
             


If ($queryreults)
 {
    $queryreults | ConvertTo-Html -Head $header | Out-File  C:\temp\File.html
    
    $JobReport = [system.io.file]::ReadAllText('C:\temp\File.html')
    $count = $queryreults.Count
    $file = "C:\temp\File.html"

    $emailSmtpServer = "exhange.server.com"
    $emailSmtpServerPort = "25"
    $emailSmtpUser = $useremail
    $emailSmtpPass = $userpw
    
    $emailFrom = "jose@gmail.com"
    $emailTo = "maria@gmail.com"
    #$emailcc = "EMAIL@gmail.com"
    #$emailBcc = "EMAIL@gmail.com"

    $emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage( $emailFrom , $emailTo )
    #$emailMessage.cc.add($emailcc)
    $emailmessage.Bcc.Add($emailBcc)
    $emailMessage.Subject = "SUBJECT" 
    $emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true
    $emailMessage.Body = "<p>BODY <br> <br> </p>" +  "$jobReport"
    #$emailMessage.Attachments = $file
    
    $SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient( $emailSmtpServer , 
    $emailSmtpServerPort )
    $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $False
    $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $emailSmtpUser , 
    $emailSmtpPass );
    $SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessage )


}
 else 
 {
         Exit
 }
```

Comment: Convert the results to CSV format, select the email property to get an email list, then use that name to match the line to send the email to the user.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input will get back to you on my test and results

Comment: No worries, just remember PowerShell and the MS PowerShellGallery.com modules --- ```Find-Module -Name '*html' | Format-Table -AutoSize``` --- offers native output to HTML format, i.e.; ```ConvertTo-Html```, and Send-MailMessage has a switch ```-BodyAsHtml```, which can also be leveraged to get that formatting in the email, without having to code it up manually. Well, unless you are wanting more color in that email body.

Comment: yes that is how i am currently formatting my querys with convert-to-html and attaching it to the body of the email and simple css formatting.

Comment: copy that... ;-}

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very rough idea of what I mean from my comment.
Yet, if you can make your SQL dump to CSV, then it's just a matter of the latter part addressing your scenario.

Others, I am sure will provide more elegant approaches.

Create the SQL data file

```
Clear-Host
@'
151      11     1588        900       0.06   Jose@gmail.com       jose                                                                                                                                                    
235      14     4024       2408              Frank@gmail.com     Frank                                                                                                                                                  
328      17     4936       3728              Frank@gmail.com     Frank                                                                                                                                                  
169      10     1744       3064       0.05   Maria@gmail.com      Maria 
'@ | 
Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\SqlEmailList,txt'
```

Convert the SQl data file to CSV

```
Clear-Host
$RecordList = ((Get-COntent -Path 'D:\Temp\SqlEmailList,txt').TrimEnd() -replace '\s{5}', "`t")  -replace '\s{3}', "`t" | 
COnvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Header Handles, NPM_K_, PM_K_, WS_K_, CPU_s_, email, Name 

Clear-Host
$RecordList.Count
# Results
<#
4
#>


Clear-Host
$RecordList | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
Handles NPM_K_ PM_K_ WS_K_ CPU_s_ email           Name 
------- ------ ----- ----- ------ -----           ---- 
151     11     1588  900   0.06   Jose@gmail.com  jose 
235     14     4024  2408         Frank@gmail.com Frank
328     17     4936  3728         Frank@gmail.com Frank
169     10     1744  3064  0.05   Maria@gmail.com Maria
#>
```

Parse the data for consolidation of email records

```
Clear-Host
$RecordList | 
Group-Object -Property Name | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
Count Name  Group                                                                                                                                                      
----- ----  -----                                                                                                                                                      
    1 jose  {@{Handles=151; NPM_K_=11; PM_K_=1588; WS_K_=900; CPU_s_=0.06; email=Jose@gmail.com; Name=jose}}                                                           
    2 Frank {@{Handles=235; NPM_K_=14; PM_K_=4024; WS_K_=2408; CPU_s_=; email=Frank@gmail.com; Name=Frank}, @{Handles=328; NPM_K_=17; PM_K_=4936; WS_K_=3728; CPU_s_...
    1 Maria {@{Handles=169; NPM_K_=10; PM_K_=1744; WS_K_=3064; CPU_s_=0.05; email=Maria@gmail.com; Name=Maria}}  
#>



Clear-Host
$RecordList.SyncRoot.email
# Results
<#
Jose@gmail.com
Frank@gmail.com
Frank@gmail.com
Maria@gmail.com
#>
```

Parse the records for unique email addresses

```
Clear-Host
$RecordList.SyncRoot.email | 
Select-Object -Unique
# Results
<#
Jose@gmail.com
Frank@gmail.com
Maria@gmail.com
#>
```

Match unique email to SQL records

```
Clear-Host
$RecordList.SyncRoot.email | 
Select-Object -Unique | 
ForEach-Object {
    $RecordList -match $PSItem | 
    Format-Table -AutoSize
}
# Results
<#
Handles NPM_K_ PM_K_ WS_K_ CPU_s_ email          Name
------- ------ ----- ----- ------ -----          ----
151     11     1588  900   0.06   Jose@gmail.com jose



Handles NPM_K_ PM_K_ WS_K_ CPU_s_ email           Name 
------- ------ ----- ----- ------ -----           ---- 
235     14     4024  2408         Frank@gmail.com Frank
328     17     4936  3728         Frank@gmail.com Frank



Handles NPM_K_ PM_K_ WS_K_ CPU_s_ email           Name 
------- ------ ----- ----- ------ -----           ---- 
169     10     1744  3064  0.05   Maria@gmail.com Maria
#>
```

Create generic email use case

```
Clear-Host
$RecordList.SyncRoot.email | 
Select-Object -Unique | 
ForEach-Object {
    $paramblock = @{
        From    = $PSItem
        To      = 'User02 <user02@fabrikam.com>'
        Subject = 'Test mail'
        Body    = $RecordList -match $PSItem | 
                  Select-Object -Property Handles, NPM_K_, PM_K_ ,WS_K_, CPU_s_
    }

    $paramblock
    # Send-MailMessage @paramblock
}
# Results
<#
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                   
----                           -----                                                                                                                                   
Subject                        Test mail                                                                                                                               
From                           Jose@gmail.com                                                                                                                          
To                             User02 <user02@fabrikam.com>                                                                                                            
Body                           @{Handles=151; NPM_K_=11; PM_K_=1588; WS_K_=900; CPU_s_=0.06}                                                                           

Subject                        Test mail                                                                                                                               
From                           Frank@gmail.com                                                                                                                         
To                             User02 <user02@fabrikam.com>                                                                                                            
Body                           {@{Handles=235; NPM_K_=14; PM_K_=4024; WS_K_=2408; CPU_s_=}, @{Handles=328; NPM_K_=17; PM_K_=4936; WS_K_=3728; CPU_s_=}}                

Subject                        Test mail                                                                                                                               
From                           Maria@gmail.com                                                                                                                         
To                             User02 <user02@fabrikam.com>                                                                                                            
Body                           @{Handles=169; NPM_K_=10; PM_K_=1744; WS_K_=3064; CPU_s_=0.05}                                                                          
#>
```

Of course, other tweaking and formatting are required to pretty this up, but this was just to give you a push in a potential direction.